# How to testing the probability of two factors being found together?

Tags: r, sampling

I know how many times a particular factors has been found:

`values<-cbind(f=c("S1","S10","S3","S4","S5","S6","S7","S8","S9"),count=c(9,8,4,24,20,4,8,21,5))`

I also have information on the number of times factors are found alone, in pairs, triplets ...

```
together<-cbind(count=c(25,11,11,1,1,0,2,0),fnb=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

S4 and S5 are found together in 13 cases which seems very high compared to any of the other associations. I would like to work out whether these two factors are more frequently found together than you would expect if the factors were randomly associated.
How do you formulate this into a statistical test?

Any help is very much appreciated.